# How do I go about differentiating $p(x)=f(g(x))-x^2h(x)$?

Tags: calculus

I have to differentiate $$p(x)=f(g(x))-x^2h(x)$$ Which rules do I use? I'm not sure which rules to use and from where to start.

Comment: Chain rule and product rule

Comment: So chain rule is for the f(g(x)) and product rule is for x^2 h(x)?

Answer (score 1):

$ \begin{align*}
        \frac{d}{dx} (f(g(x))-x^2h(x))
        &= \frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) - \frac{d}{dx} x^2h(x) & \text{Derivative is linear} \\
        &= f'(g(x)) g'(x) - (2x h(x) + x^2h'(x)) & \text{Chain Rule and Product Rule} \\
    \end{align*}$